# iOS XCode Add the scrollbar indicator program programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, object, scrollbar

I'm currently coding a iOS apps that contains a **scrollview in the mainview**. When the user want to reset the scrollview I'm running this method:

```
-(void)clearFlightTimer{
    // Removing object (button, label and image) from subview
    // *** KNOWN BUG WHEN REMOVING UIImageView OBJECT IT'S ALSO REMOVING THE SCROLLBAR IMAGE ***
    for(UIView *subview in [self.flightViewScrollView subviews]) {
        if([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]] || [subview isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]] || [subview isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
        } else {
            // Do nothing - not a UIButton or subclass instance
        }
    }

    // Reloading the View
    [self viewDidLoad];
    [self viewWillAppear:(YES)];
}
```

The issue is that the scrollbar seem to be part of UIImageView class and this method remove it. How could I keep the scrollbar image when removing all object from this subview? Is there a way to **code the scrollbar indicator** back programmatically?

Thanks!

Hope that I'm clear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest and most fool proof way is probably to add an intermediate subview of the scroll view that contains your actual content.  This new container view's subviews can be iterated over and removed as you need.  Alternatively, if you know the scroll view is in an empty state, you might be able to iterate over subviews of the scrollview and store all image views that exist when empty - those views will be the ones you shouldn't mess with.

Comment: That's what I'm gonna do. Thanks!